# Azure API Management Service custom domain

Tags: azure-api-management, custom-domain

We have an Azure API Management Service and we need to configure  custom domain with custom SSL certificate. We have it added to the custom domain section of the service as Proxy endpoint and have a certificate uploaded too. The deployed APIs reports the new hostname in Settings > Base URL but when I invoke the API url it replys with "Unknown host".

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you done CNAME mapping of the Custom Domain to <serviceName>.azure-api.net in your DNS?

Comment: Have you attached this APIM insatnce inside VNET ?

Comment: Hope you have followed all the steps here,https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/configure-custom-domain

Comment: @Samir nope, Should I do that? It isn't reported on the MS guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/configure-custom-domain

Comment: @Premier it's mentioned somehow vaguely. Notice point three in Prerequisites section. The basic idea is that provisioning custom domain in APIM allows it to accept requests sent to that hostname. But to make clients actually send requests to correct IP address you need to configure DNS externally.